# With which event can I view the 'MEMBER_DISCONNECT' audit log?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is the code:

```
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", async function(oldMember, newMember){

const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("586962324544553011");
const entry = await guild.fetchAuditLogs({type: 'MEMBER_DISCONNECT'}).then(audit => audit.entries.first())

console.log(entry);
    
});
```

My problem here is that when every user leaves the room, the latest log console drops.
Even if the person is not disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the proper form of the code .

You need to ask for Voice Update via old member and new member !

Old member is using when someone is disconnecting from a (old) voice channel(state).

In order to display your disconnected members you have to use :

```
(`${oldVoiceState.member} disconnected from ${oldVoiceState.channel.name}.`);
```

So the proper way is to ask for 'connected' members and then ask for 'disconnected' members:

You can try this :

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldVoiceState, newVoiceState) => {
    if (newVoiceState.channel) {
    console.log(`${newVoiceState.member} connected to ${newVoiceState.channel.name}.`);
        
    } else if (oldVoiceState.channel) {
    console.log(`${oldVoiceState.member} disconnected from ${oldVoiceState.channel.name}.`);
        
    }
});
```

Comment: I do not want to do this.Send a daily message when the disconnect button is enabled after right clicking. I want to do this